# Editing SQL in Triggers with code

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2012, ssms

I have been migrating a database from SQL Server 2008 to 2012 and there have been problems with triggers that contain RAISERROR, because the syntax has changed between version. Now I could go through and change all of these manually, but that is a whole days work in itself.

Ideally there is a way where I can get a program to go into the triggers and change the RAISERRORs to the new syntax, this will be useful because I will upgrading another server soon and would speed up that process as well.

I have looked into SSMS Add-ins and believe they can directly edit the code within a trigger but the documentation is sparse.
I don't believe it can be done through SQL itself they can only ALTER TRIGGER, whereas I want to actually change the code inside the trigger.

Comment: I think this is your exact same problem http://tomaslind.net/2014/12/10/mass-editing-sql-server-objects/